# How to chain objects of mixed types in PHP5

Tags: php, oop, chaining

I'd like to chain-reference a string property like this:

```
echo($object1->object2->stringProperty);
```

But that yields this error:

**Catchable fatal error: Object of class [object 2's type] could not be converted to string**

Can I make this work by forcing a typecast somewhere in there? It works to use an intermediate variable for the middle object, but that adds unfortunate cruft:

```
class foo {
    public $bar;
}

class bar {
    public $title;
}

// Initialize the example.
$myBar = new bar();
$myFoo = new foo();
$myFoo->bar = $myBar;
$myBar->title = "fubar";

// Using an intermediate object works.
$temp = $myFoo->bar;
echo("$temp->title<br />");

// Using a direct reference raises a fatal error.
echo("$myFoo->bar->title<br />");
```

Comment: @sam-dufel $object 2 is an object. In the example code above, it's class bar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either remove the quotes:

```
echo $myFoo->bar->title . "<br />";
```

or place in braces (also known as complex syntax):

```
echo "{$myFoo->bar->title}<br />";
```